# How to create marginal notes without 'opening up' the paragraph

Tags: marginpar, e-tex

This is an example with the `\marginalstar` macro from *TeXbook*.
Without `\marginalstar` the paragraph is normal, with `\marginalstar` the paragraph is "opened up".

```
\def\strutdepth{\dp\strutbox}
\def\marginalstar{\strut\vadjust{\kern-\strutdepth\specialstar}}
\def\specialstar{%
  \vtop to \strutdepth{
    \baselineskip\strutdepth
    \vss
    \llap{* }
    \null
  }%
}
\nopagenumbers
\hsize0.8in
\noindent
Quick brown fox eats a
\marginalstar
fat big
\vrule height 9pt width 2pt depth 0pt
mouse.
\bye
```

Is there any TeX engine or LaTeX/ConTeXt package which can produce the same output as in the above example, but not to "open up" the paragraph? (i.e., is there a solution without using `\strut`)

Comment: But not e.g. `\marginpar[]{}`? Obviously that is a LaTeX command rather than a LaTeX package, but I'm a bit confused as to what you want exactly.

Comment: Have a look at the todonotes package, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you use TikZ, you can overlay a picture including the asterisk without disturbing the text of the paragraph. If you use the `tikzmark` library, you can easily mark the relevant vertical coordinate. With the `tikzpagenodes` package, you can easily get the relevant horizontal coordinate.

TikZ can be used with plain TeX, ConTeXt and with Tex, pdfTeX, XeTeX and LuaTeX. However, the `tikzpagenodes` and `tikzmark` packages require the LaTeX format, I think.

Here's a LaTeX example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\hsize0.8in
\noindent
Quick brown fox eats a
\tikzmark{a}%
fat big
\vrule height 9pt width 2pt depth 0pt
mouse.
\begin{tikzpicture} [overlay,remember picture]
  \node [anchor=east] at ({pic cs:a} -| current page text area.west) {*};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: unopened paragraph]

To make this more convenient, you can wrap it in a new command. This version also uses `yshift` to move the star up slightly relative to the baseline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcounter{mystar}
\setcounter{mystar}{0}
\newcommand\specialstar{%
  \stepcounter{mystar}%
  \tikzmark{\arabic{mystar}}%
  \tikz[overlay, remember picture] \node [anchor=east, yshift=.25em] at ({pic cs:\arabic{mystar}} -| current page text area.west) {*};}
\begin{document}
\hsize0.8in
\noindent
Quick brown fox eats a
\specialstar%
fat big
\vrule height 9pt width 2pt depth 0pt
mouse.

\noindent
Quick brown fox eats a
\specialstar%
$\frac{a^n + b^n}{\frac{\frac{c}{a^n}}{b^n - c^n}}$
big fat
\vrule height 9pt width 2pt depth 0pt
mouse.

\noindent
Quick
$\frac{a^n + b^n}{\frac{\frac{c}{a^n}}{b^n - c^n}}$
eats a
\specialstar%
big fat
\vrule height 9pt width 2pt depth 0pt
juicy mouse.

\noindent
Quick brown fox eats a
\specialstar%
big fat
\vrule height 9pt width 2pt depth 0pt
$\frac{a^n + b^n}{\frac{\frac{c}{a^n}}{b^n - c^n}}$
mouse.

\end{document}
```

and shows that it works regardless of the height and depth of the line, the previous line and the following line:

[image: demo]

Comment: To precise my question: I want to do the same task as in exercise 14.28 of *TeXbook*, but the solution must be universal, i.e., not assuming anything about the height of the next line or the depth of the previous line or the depth of the line containing the marginalstar (which is done in Knuth's solution, considering the fact that it uses `\strut`).

Comment: This is what your example produces in my stock debian 9 texlive installation: http://expirebox.com/download/c21e5b34d1d399db5d10080a021ed96b.html

Comment: @IgorLiferenko I can't see the file you linked to. (I press 'download' and it just reloads the current page.) However, you do need to compile at least twice for this to work. But this solution is 'universal' in the sense you specify: the height and depth of lines makes no difference because the `tikzpicture` is overlaid on top. (If the position of the asterisk is wrong, it will happily put it on top of the text for this reason.) No space is used for the asterisk, if you like: it is up to you to make sure it is somewhere where there is space, such as the margin. But Debian's TL may be too old.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko `tikzmark` requires LaTeX, though. (Might work with ConTeXt, too - I'm not sure. Doesn't work with plain, though.)

Comment: After running second time it worked, sorry. Your solution is good. The only thing I'm not sure about is that it lines up the baselines of margin content and corresponding line in the paragraph - the asterisk seems lower than it should be. What is the principle which this tikz package uses to calculate the reference point of the margins text? Is it based on `\vadjust` or something other?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Please see edit above.

Comment: I get it now - the placement of the margin text is calculated during second pass: when I did only one run, the asterisk was somewhere far away from necessary place. It is during this second run that the proper position is calculated - after all line breaking is already known. This is just what I need. This "second run" is very curious... How does it work exactly? I would like to implement the same technique with plain.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko The `tikzmark` package was developed on the basis of answers to questions on this site. If you search for `tikzmark`, you can find earlier versions of the code with explanations and details. Or you can look at the implementation details in the package itself. The `overlay, remember picture` stuff always needs a second run. On the first run, I think it is using some default coordinate - if you have lots of overlaid nodes, they all get bunched together until the second compilation. I'm sure you can do it with plain - `tikzmark` uses `\newcommand` but you could redo that.